How to get rid of the default, i.e., "plain", page numbers?
I'm trying to create a template for my math course and I'm facing some problems as I'm not experienced in working with LaTeX. This is the MWE :
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,twocolumn, landscape]{extreport}

% Page Layout and Formatting
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=1.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,headsep=105mm]{geometry} % Set page margins
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt} % Add rule between columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm} % Set space between columns

% Custom page headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancybox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\fancyfoot{gobble} % Remove standard page numbering in footer
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% Color support
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Sans-serif fonts for document
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath % Set math font to sans-serif

% Load other packages (organized)
\usepackage{soul} % Provides highlighting and underlining
\usepackage{float} % Improves positioning of figures and tables
\usepackage{sidecap} % Enables side captions
\usepackage{pifont} % Access to Dingbats symbols
\usepackage{makecell} % Allows multiline cells in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Allows multirow cells in tables
\usepackage{multicol} % Allows multicolumn layout
\usepackage{graphicx} % Supports including images
\usepackage{gensymb} % Provides generic symbols
\usepackage[many,most]{tcolorbox} % Boxes with customizable colors
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % Allows boxes to break across pages
\tcbuselibrary{theorems} % Provides theorems inside boxes
\usepackage{stackengine} % Stacks elements on top of each other
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{varwidth} % Provides variable width minipages
\usepackage{tabularx} % Extends tabular with adjustable-width columns
\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}


% Additional graphics support (organized)
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows text to wrap around figures
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Creates plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % Sets compatibility for pgfplots
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % Boxes with customizable colors
\tcbuselibrary{skins} % Additional skins for boxes
\usepackage{tikz} % Creates graphics programmatically
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Frames around boxes
\usepackage{array} % Extends array and tabular environments
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % Adds coordinate calculations

% Define colors
\definecolor{Gold}{HTML}{F2BF5E}

% Custom chapter styles
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} 

% Define a new counter for the definition number
\newcounter{cnt}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\thecnt}{\thesection.\alph{cnt}}

% Define a new environment with boxed text, TikZ drawing, and counter
\newtcolorbox[use counter=cnt]{mydef}[1]{
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=Gold,
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-.7\baselineskip,},
  title={Définition : #1},
  coltitle=black, % Set title color to black
  before upper=\vspace{1.5ex},
  boxed title style={%
    empty,
    left=0pt,
    overlay unbroken and first={%
      \node [circle,fill=Gold,minimum size=7mm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center] (circle) at (frame.east) {};
      \node (n1) [fill=Gold,anchor=east,minimum height=7mm,minimum width={width("Définition : #1")+8mm}] at (frame.east) {};
      \node (c1) [circle,fill=Gold,minimum size=7mm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center]  at (n1.west) {};
      \node (c2) [fill=black,line width=2pt,circle,draw=Gold,minimum size=8mm,anchor=center] at (c1) {\textcolor{Gold}{\thetcbcounter}};
    },
  },
}


%--------------------------stylepages-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[Gold]([yshift=1cm]current page.south west)rectangle(current page.south east) ;
        \node[cloud,draw=black,line width=2pt,minimum size=0.5cm,fill=Gold]at([yshift=0.9cm]current page.south){$ {\color{black}\thepage} $};
        %\node[anchor=west]at([yshift=.5cm]current page.south west){{ \textbf{\color{black}\qrcode[height=0.3cm]{www.facebook.com }}}};
        \node[anchor=east]at([yshift=.5cm]current page.south east){{ \textbf{\color{black}MAAROUF MAROUAN}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent=0mm


%--------------------------Subsection formating----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{subsection}}}
\tikzstyle{c} = [rectangle,draw,rounded corners=2mm,draw=black,line width=1pt,fill=Gold,minimum height=0mm,align=left,inner sep=2mm,font=\bfseries]
\def\subsecbox#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
\node[right,c] (0,0){\thesubsection{} -- #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent=0mm
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\subsecbox{#1}}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}


\begin{mydef}{A definition}
  This is a definition

\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}{ }
  This is a definition
\end{mydef}

\newpage


\section{Second section}
\vspace{2cm}
\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{mydef}{A definition}
  This is a definition
\end{mydef}
\end{document}

So my question is :
How can I get rid of the default ("plain") page numbers in the center footer so they don't show up duplicated ?
Thank you in advance, and sorry for my english.


Thank you @mico for the clarification. I made the appropriate adjustments.


How can I get rid of the default page numbering in the center footer so it doesn't show duplicated

This issue arises because \pagestyle{plain} is in effect by default on pages with chapter headings. (The table of contents header page counts as a chapter heading page.) To get rid of this setting, section 11 of the user guide of the fancyhdr package recommends running
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

after loading the fancyhdr package.
In the definition of \subsecbox, I suggest using \columnwidth instead of \textwidth to set the maximal horizontal width of the decorative line. I would reduce the thickness of the "cloud" around the page numbers.

\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,9pt,landscape]{extreport}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% Page Layout and Formatting
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=1.5cm,headsep=105mm]%
           {geometry} % page margins
%%%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt} % Add rule between columns %%% bad idea
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm} % Set whitespace between columns

% Custom page headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%%,fancybox} % do you really need 'fancybox'?
\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}        % <--- new
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % <--- new

\usepackage{lastpage}

% Color support
\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\textcolor' macro
\definecolor{Gold}{HTML}{F2BF5E}

% Sans-serif fonts for document
\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath % Set math font to sans-serif

% Load other packages (organized)
\usepackage{soul} % Provides highlighting and underlining
%%%\usepackage{float} % Improves positioning of figures and tables %%% not true!
\usepackage{sidecap} % Enables side captions
\usepackage{pifont} % Access to Dingbats symbols
\usepackage{makecell} % Allows multiline cells in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Allows multirow cells in tables
%%%\usepackage{multicol} % Allows multicolumn layout
\usepackage{graphicx} % Supports including images
\usepackage{gensymb} % Provides generic symbols

\usepackage[many,most]{tcolorbox} % Boxes with customizable colors
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % Allows boxes to break across pages
\tcbuselibrary{theorems} % Provides theorems inside boxes
\tcbuselibrary{skins} % Additional skins for boxes

\usepackage{stackengine} % Stacks elements on top of each other

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{varwidth} % Provides variable width minipages
\usepackage{tabularx} % Extends tabular with adjustable-width columns
\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists

\usepackage{tikz} % Create graphics programmatically
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % Adds coordinate calculations

\usepackage{eso-pic} %%% are you sure you need this?

%%%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % don't load packages twice

% Additional graphics support (organized)
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows text to wrap around figures
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Creates plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % Sets compatibility for pgfplots

%%%\usepackage{tcolorbox} % don't load packages twice

%%%%\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Frames around boxes 
   %%% not a good idea to load both 'tcolorbox' and 'mdframed' machineries
   
\usepackage{array} % Extends array and tabular environments

% Custom chapter styles
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} 

% Define a new counter for the definition number
\newcounter{cnt}[subsection] %%% or, rather, '[section]' ??
\renewcommand{\thecnt}{\thesection.\alph{cnt}}

% Define a new environment with boxed text, TikZ drawing, and counter
\newtcolorbox[use counter=cnt]{mydef}[1]{
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=Gold,
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-.7\baselineskip,},
  title={Définition\;: #1},
  coltitle=black, % Set title color to black
  before upper=\vspace{1.5ex},
  boxed title style={%
    empty,
    left=0pt,
    overlay unbroken and first={%
      \node [circle,fill=Gold,minimum size=7mm,
             inner sep=0pt,anchor=center] (circle) at (frame.east) {};
      \node (n1) [fill=Gold,anchor=east,minimum height=7mm,
                  minimum width={width("Définition\;: #1")+8mm}] at (frame.east) {};
      \node (c1) [circle,fill=Gold,minimum size=7mm,
                  inner sep=0pt,anchor=center]  at (n1.west) {};
      \node (c2) [fill=black,line width=2pt,circle,
                  draw=Gold,minimum size=8mm,anchor=center] at (c1) 
                  {\textcolor{Gold}{\bfseries\thetcbcounter}};
}}}

%----------------- style pages ----------------
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[Gold]([yshift=1cm]current page.south west) 
              rectangle(current page.south east) ;
        \node[cloud,draw=black,line width=0.8pt, % '2pt' is much too heavy
              minimum size=0.5cm,fill=Gold]at([yshift=1cm] % 0.9cm seems weird
              current page.south){\textcolor{black}{\thepage}};
        \node[anchor=east]at([yshift=.5cm]current page.south east){%
              \textcolor{black}{\bfseries Maarouf Marouan }};
              %%% why all-uppercase?
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent=0mm

%------------- Subsection formating ---------------
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{subsection}}}
\tikzstyle{c} = [rectangle,draw,rounded corners=2mm, 
                 draw=black,line width=0.5pt,fill=Gold,
                 minimum height=0mm,align=left,
                 inner sep=2mm, font=\bfseries]
\def\subsecbox#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[black,line width=0.5pt] (0,0) -- (\columnwidth,0);
  \node[right,c] (0,0){\thesubsection{} -- #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent=0mm %%% is this setting supposed to be global?
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{}{0em}{\subsecbox{#1}}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection of Section \thesection}

\begin{mydef}{A definition}
  This is a definition
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}{\unskip} % better '\unskip' than blank space
  This is a definition
\end{mydef}

\newpage % in two-column mode, this forces a column break

\section{Second section}

%%\vspace{2cm} %%% why?
\subsection{First Subsection of Section \thesection}

\begin{mydef}{A definition}
  This is a definition
\end{mydef}

\subsection{Second Subsection of Section \thesection}

\begin{mydef}{A definition}
  This is a definition
\end{mydef}

\end{document}


Thank you @Mico, that's exactly what I was looking for.
